# Repeat ndarray n times

Tags: python, numpy, repeat

I have a `numpy.ndarray` with `True`/`False`:

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([True, True, False])
```

I want:

```
out = np.array([True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False])
```

I tried:

```
np.repeat(a, 3, axis = 0)
```

But it duplicates each element, I want to duplicate the all array.

This is the closes I got:

```
np.array([a for i in range(3)])
```

However, I want it to stay as 1D.

## Edit

It was suggested to be a duplicate of [Repeating each element of a numpy array 5 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471878/repeating-each-element-of-a-numpy-array-5-times). However, my question was how to repeat the **all** array and **not** each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [np.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

```
>>> a = np.array([True, True, False])
>>> np.tile(a, 3)
... array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([True, True, False])
print(np.concatenate([a]*3))

[ True  True False  True  True False  True  True False]
```