# Duplicate numpy Array Multiple times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy

I have an array of binary elements size `(100,)`.

I'd like to copy it 8 times, keeping the elements the same and store it as a new array size `(800,)`

`np.copy()` can copy it once, but how can I go about copying it 8 times?

Comment: Do you mean cycle through the elements 8 times or do you mean repeat each element 8 times and then move onto the next one?

Comment: Well here are the two options for the different cases I referred to above: `np.tile(a, 8)` for the first and `np.repeat(a, 8)` for the second.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25471878/13552470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use [numpy.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). It repeats array's elements by specifying repeat number:

```
new_arr = numpy.repeat(old_arr, 8)
```